# Xcode OS X Storyboards: How do I get a reference to the top level "window content" view controller?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard, nswindowcontroller, nstabviewcontroller

I have a basic Cocoa app to try out Swift and Storyboards.

The app consists of 3 main views that are managed by an `NSTabViewController`, which again is linked to the main window's "window content" relationship.

I added an `NSSegmentedControl` to the window's toolbar to switch between the 3 tab views.

In the main window controller I added the action method for the toolbar item to switch between the tabs, but I can't figure out how to get a reference to the tab view controller to actually switch tabs.

I tried adding my action method to the tab view controller, but that does not work, because the tab view controller might not be in the responder chain  if it contains an empty view (is this a bug?).

As a workaround, I overrode viewDidAppear() in the tab view controller. There I get a handle to the view.window.windowController and set a reference to "self" in an instance variable. This works, but does not seem right. There should be a way to get from the window controller to it's content view controller...

The window controller and tab view controllers live in different scenes, to I can't connect them through IBOutlet. Also, none of the segue methods are called on the window controller either for the "window content" relationship.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Hey mark. I'm running into *precisely* the same problem. Do you remember what you ended up doing to achieve this?  Here's an outline of my problem: https://gitlab.com/AMomchilov/public/experiments/app-startup-structure-demo

Comment: I think I ended up traversing `contentViewController?.children` looking for my tab view controller. Not relevant for this particular case, but something very useful to know about is `NSResponder.supplementalTarget(forAction:sender:)`. I use this all the time to expose objects in my window controller that are not directly part of the responder chain to forward actions to from menus and the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm incredibly late, and maybe it didn't exist when that question was posted, but for anyone landing here, the `NSWindowController` has a `contentViewController: NSViewController?` property (added in macOS 10.10, so around the end of 2014 I think).

Answer (score 0):

I'm mainly an OS X guy, and I'm new to StoryBoards myself, but I think what you need to do is:

1. Write your

   -(IBAction)someResponse:(id)sender {}

method in the view controller that plans to handle the action.

2. Wire the Control so that it sends its action to its FirstResponder. If your view controller is in the responder chain, it'll receive it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is that the tab view controller that implements the action is not in the responder chain if the action is triggered by a toolbar item. Also, I was not able to figure out how to connect outlets across view controller scenes (simple master/detail view). For now, I returned to plain old nib files.

Comment: It's a kludge, but I implement the IBAction in my WindowController and pass it down. I had a similar situation with SplitViews. If you put an IBAction in a ViewController, that only gets called if the ViewController is in focus.

Comment: You don't connect outlets across scenes in a storyboard, as nearly as I can tell. The controller that owns the sub controller passes whatever data it needs to pass via "prepareForSegue", and then you pass your data back via other mechanisms like notifications or delegates. (I'm new to storyboards; I've only dabbled with iOS, and Hillegass doesn't believe in them, so it's only now that I'm trying them out)